# split string to numbers and not numbers

Tags: python, regex, string

```
In [115]: string = '2.5x2'

In [116]: re.split('(\d+.\d+)', string)
Out[116]: ['', '2.5', 'x2']

In [117]: re.split('(\d+)', string)
Out[117]: ['', '2', '.', '5', 'x', '2', '']
```

I need to find regexp which will give me

> ['', '2.5', 'x', '2']

Comment: what's the point of the first empty item?

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+|\D+', s)`

Answer (score 4):

Use `re.findall()` with an optional capture group:

```
In [7]: re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[a-z]', string)
Out[7]: ['2.5', 'x', '2']
```

If you want to match upperase letters too use `re.I` flag for ignoring the case.

```
re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[a-z]', string, re.I)
```

Comment: In [120]: re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[a-z]', 'M10')
Out[120]: ['10']  **It should be ['M', '10']**

Comment: @timKa, `M` is a capital letter, but the regex doesn't capture capital letters, which can be fixed easily.

Comment: @timKa It seems that OP is dealing with hex-like strings, but for sake of completeness I updated the code!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` with a capturing group:

```
>>> s = '2.5x2'
>>> print re.split(r'(\d*\.?\d+)', s)
['', '2.5', 'x', '2', '']
```

If you want to remove empty elements then use:

```
>>> print filter(None, re.split(r'(\d*\.?\d+)', s))
['2.5', 'x', '2']
```